# sendgrid in classic asp add email category

Tags: asp-classic, asp.net-web-api, sendgrid

I'm sending mail using sendgrid web API successfully but unable add categories into x-smtpapi.
Here is my code  :

```
function getHTML (strUrl,postData)
    Set xmlHttp = Server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlHttp.Open "POST", strUrl, False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "asp httprequest"
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    'xmlHttp.AddHeader "category", "web"         
    xmlHttp.Send postData

    getHTML = xmlHttp.responseText
    xmlHttp.abort()
    set xmlHttp = Nothing   
end function

Response.Write("test->" & getHTML("https://sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json","api_user=myusername&api_key=mykey&to=soneone@somemail.com&subject=test-1 msg&html=this is test message&from=info@zyxxxz.com&category={testweb}"))
Response.End()
```

I've checked some doc [here](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/index.html)

But I could not find any way to add categories.

**EDIT**

```
Response.Write("test->" & getHTML("https://sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json","api_user=user&api_key=key&to=somemail@somemail.com&subject=test-1 msg&html=this is test message&from=info@xyzzz.com&x-smtpapi={"category":"testCategory"}"))
```

I need to post it JSON. If I do not put double quote **x-smtpapi={"category":"testCategory"}"** JSON parser can't parse it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double double quote escapes in ASP:

Ex.

```
#Invalid
str = " She said "Hello World" to the whole group"

#valid
str = " She said ""Hello World"" to the whole group"
```

So this should work fine:

```
Response.Write("test->" & getHTML("https://sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json","api_user=user&api_key=key&to=somemail@somemail.com&subject=test-1 msg&html=this is test message&from=info@xyzzz.com&x-smtpapi={""category"":""testCategory""}"))
```